# Error code 23514 in postgresql when insert into partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger, check-constraints

I have a table in postgresql with the structure such as:

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_event_firebase
(
    user_id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    event_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    timestamp bigint NOT NULL,
    platform character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
)
```

and I created some partition table via month such as `tableA_YYYY_MM`  with YYYY is year, MM is month by procedure such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_partition_table_function(date, date)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    create_query text;
    index_query text;
BEGIN
    FOR create_query, index_query IN SELECT
            'create table if not exists user_event_firebase_'
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || '() inherits ( user_event_firebase );',
            'create index if not exists user_event_firebase_'
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || '_time on user_event_firebase_'
            || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_MM' )
            || ' ( timestamp,event_name,platform,user_id );'
        FROM generate_series( $1, $2, '1 month' ) AS d
    LOOP
        EXECUTE create_query;
        EXECUTE index_query;
    END LOOP;
END;
$function$
```

I've been created insert into these partitioned table with insert_by_partition_function_3 function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_by_partition_function_3()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN        
    EXECUTE 'insert into user_event_firebase_'
            || to_char(to_timestamp(NEW.timestamp / 1000), 'YYYY_MM' )
            || ' values ( $1, $2, $3, $4 )' USING NEW.user_id, NEW.event_name, NEW.timestamp, NEW.platform;
        RETURN NULL;

END;
$function$
```

Apply trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER partition_trigger_function_1
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON user_event_firebase
    FOR each ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_by_partition_function_3() ;
```

But when I insert into these partitioned table. It throw an error about  **23514 : check_violation [Integrity Constraint Violation]**

> {"name":"error","length":539,"severity":"ERROR","code":"23514","detail":"Failing
>   row contains (5abd344fa9dd172024b8b661, reg_wal_continue_v6,
>   1522530933094, ios, 2018-09-06 17:26:54.98615).","where":"SQL
>   statement \"insert into user_event_firebase_2018_04 values ( $1, $2,
>   $3, $4 )\"\nPL/pgSQL function insert_by_partition_function_3() line 3
>   at
>   EXECUTE","schema":"public","table":"user_event_firebase_2018_04","constraint":"user_event_firebase_2018_04_created_at_check","file":"execMain.c","line":"1760","routine":"ExecConstraints"}

When I get constraint from table, I have information such as

```
"user_event_firebase_2018_04_created_at_check","2200","c",f,f,t,"60055","0","0","0"," "," "," ",t,0,f,"{5}",null,null,null,null,null,"{BOOLEXPR :boolop and :args ({OPEXPR :opno 2374 :opfuncid 2368 :opresulttype 16 :opretset false :opcollid 0 :inputcollid 0 :args ({VAR :varno 1 :varattno 5 :vartype 1114 :vartypmod -1 :varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 :varnoold 1 :varoattno 5 :location 64} {CONST :consttype 1082 :consttypmod -1 :constcollid 0 :constlen 4 :constbyval true :constisnull false :location 83 :constvalue 4 [ 9 26 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]}) :location 75} {OPEXPR :opno 2371 :opfuncid 2364 :opresulttype 16 :opretset false :opcollid 0 :inputcollid 0 :args ({VAR :varno 1 :varattno 5 :vartype 1114 :vartypmod -1 :varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 :varnoold 1 :varoattno 5 :location 100} {CONST :consttype 1082 :consttypmod -1 :constcollid 0 :constlen 4 :constbyval true :constisnull false :location 118 :constvalue 4 [ 39 26 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]}) :location 111}) :location 96}","((created_at >= '2018-04-01'::date) AND (created_at < '2018-05-01'::date))"
```

[image]

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Regards.

Comment: Your check constraint is `((created_at >= '2018-04-01'::date) AND (created_at < '2018-05-01'::date))` and you're inserting `2018-09-06 17:26:54.98615`. Or more precisely, "you" are inserting nothing in there, and that field is setup to default to `now()`, hence you get a timestamp outside your check range.

Comment: @eurotrash you saved me for today